# Can I define scheduled tasks before naming the computer?

Tags: windows-7, deployment, scheduled-task

When scheduling a task it's scheduled as running as a specific user/group.

Can I on a vm schedule a task, then sysprep, and then deploy the image to a machine which I then name and join to a domain?

In this case I want the task to run as /users.

In the end, I tried, and it turned out to be possible after all. When the machine got renamed, the task changed also to the new name.

Comment: If you have $OEM$ folders during your install, might be easier to add/edit/remove schtasks commands from SetupComplete.cmd without having to sysprep your wim for minor changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're going to need this task on a number of machines. In that case, your best option is to use [Group Policy Scheduled Task Items](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725745.aspx). This will give you continued management of the scheduled tasks, not a one-shot like what you're describing will do.

I'm a very big fan of "thin" images where your master is as close to the Microsoft reference image as possible with configuration management tools like Group Policy and SCCM deploying software and settings post-install. The less you put into your master image, the more flexible it is.